# Is snow a transparent block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a base in the end, but there are endermen all over the place, if i cover the base in snow, would endermen be able to spawn on it?

Comment: Just try it. Point a repeater into it and see if redstone on the other side gets powered.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [wiki](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Snow_Block), snow is not transparent. I believe enderman would still be able to spawn. However, as it is with snow, if you build your base out of it any light source placed near it will cause it to melt.

[image]

Comment: That's not the official wiki, [this is](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Snow_Block), at least to some interpretations. At least it's linked on an official Mojang page. But in this case they agree anyway.

Comment: Archive link for my last comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Snow_Block&oldid=1259965